# groovy looking up weird properties

Tags: groovy

I have the following groovy script compiled from an html file

```
package org.webpieces.plugins.fortesting

import org.webpieces.ctx.api.Current

class notFound_html extends org.webpieces.templating.impl.GroovyTemplateSuperclass {
  public Object run() {
    use(org.webpieces.templating.impl.source.GroovyExtensions) {
      __out.print("<html>\n"); //htmlLine 0:2  groovyLine=8
      __out.print("  <head>\n"); //htmlLine 2:3  groovyLine=9
      __out.print("  </head>\n"); //htmlLine 3:4  groovyLine=10
      __out.print("  <body>\n"); //htmlLine 4:5  groovyLine=11
      __out.print("    Your page was not found\n"); //htmlLine 5:6  groovyLine=12
      __out.print("  </body>\n"); //htmlLine 6:7  groovyLine=13
      __out.print("</html>"); //htmlLine 7:7  groovyLine=14
    }
  }
}
```

This then compiles to a *.class file which decompiled I see looks like this

```
package org.webpieces.plugins.fortesting;

import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.transform.Generated;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GeneratedClosure;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.webpieces.templating.impl.GroovyTemplateSuperclass;

public class notFound_html extends GroovyTemplateSuperclass {
@Generated
public notFound_html() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    super();
}

public Object run() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();

    final class _run_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
        public _run_closure1(Object _outerInstance, Object _thisObject) {
            CallSite[] var3 = $getCallSiteArray();
            super(_outerInstance, _thisObject);
        }

        public Object doCall(Object it) {
            CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
            var2[0].call(var2[1].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "<html>\n");
            var2[2].call(var2[3].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "  <head>\n");
            var2[4].call(var2[5].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "  </head>\n");
            var2[6].call(var2[7].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "  <body>\n");
            var2[8].call(var2[9].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "    Your page was not found\n");
            var2[10].call(var2[11].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "  </body>\n");
            return var2[12].call(var2[13].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this), "</html>");
        }

        @Generated
        public Object doCall() {
            CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
            return this.doCall((Object)null);
        }
    }

    return var1[0].callCurrent(this, var1[1].callGetProperty(var1[2].callGetProperty(var1[3].callGetProperty(var1[4].callGetProperty(var1[5].callGetProperty(var1[6].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this)))))), new _run_closure1(this, this));
}
}
```

When running this template, I get an exception on looking up the property 'org'.  Specifically, the superclass I control GroovyTemplateSuperclass which has a getProperty method like so ->

```
@Override
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    String srcLocation = modifySourceLocation2(sourceLocal.get());

    boolean isOptional = false;
    if(property.endsWith("$")) {
        isOptional = true;
        property = property.substring(0, property.length()-1);
    }
    
    try {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        if(isOptional)
            return null;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such property '"+property+"' but perhaps you forgot quotes "
                + "around it or you forgot to pass it in from the controller's return value(with the RouteId) OR "
                + "lastly, if this is inside a custom tag, perhaps the tag did not pass in the correct arguments."+srcLocation, e);
    }
}
```

Groovy appears to be going through this line ->

```
    use(org.webpieces.templating.impl.source.GroovyExtensions) {
```

and each of those is in an array and being called as a property.  I am not sure why this is failing now and was working before though so I am providing all the info I have.

**Specifically, I get ""No such property 'org'"** and upon further inspection that comes from an array which has org, webpieces, templating, impl, source, GroovyExtensions.

I find this very strange and am still digging but thought I might post as I have a feeling I may waste hours on this one.

Comment: This is no array, this is a class reference. Is this class in the classpath? If this really confuses the parser, you can try to import it explicitly.

Comment: "I have the following groovy script compiled from an html file" - Which compiler are you using to do that?

Comment: Is `org.webpieces.templating.impl.source.GroovyExtensions` on your classpath?